# 3-body problem: Is it possible to find real moon orbit if I know kepler's orbit elements for 2body, direction to planet and real gravity force vector?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, satellites, three-body-problem

I have a system of Sun, planet and moon of planet. I can find orbit of moon using kepler's law. But distance between planet and moon is a half of distance between planet and sun.

So, if I will calculate form of moon orbit from position and velocity of moon at each moment, it will be very big when moon is between planet and sun and very small when planet is between moon and Sun.

Each celestial body has a real gravity vector which equal to vector sum of all gravity force vectors applied to body at current moment. Also, I can add additional info to each body (for i.e. pos and velocity observed at different moments at past or something else)

Is it possible to calculate the real moon orbit and predict it future position at t seconds from current observation moment (after I measure position and velocity and calculate kepler's orbital elements)? What information could I add to each body to make it possible?

Comment: Your moon orbit is too big. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere

Comment: You can use [_numerical methods_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) to estimate the future states of an N-body system, but you can not find a [_closed form expression_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) that yields exact future states of any system with more than two bodies. TLDR: Numerical methods work by animating the differential equations in tiny steps. If you estimate how much the system will change in one millisecond from its current state, and then repeat a million times, you'll have an estimate of what it will be a thousand seconds from now.

Comment: @PM2Ring Hmmmm, thank you. I will think about it

Comment: @SolomonSlow I don't need precise state, I just need an rough estimation: just to detect where should I go, to be catched by planet gravity

Comment: Maybe find some resources starting from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_simulation